# Hibernate @MappedClass polymorphism

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping

let's say I have this Class

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class A{...}
```

And This Class

```
@Entity
@Table
public class B extends {...}
```

Will I be able to handle this polymorphicaly?

```
A aParent = serviceLayer.getSubClass(Long id)
```

or like this:

```
List<A> listOfItems = serviceLayer.getSubClassAsList();
```

will both statements work?  assuming `getSubClass(Long id)`  and `getSubClassAsList` returns a `B` and a `List<B>` respectively?

Comment: `List<A> listOfItems = serviceLayer.getSubClassAsList();` will not compile, it has nothing to do with hibernate, but with the way generics works in java. List<B> is not extending List<A> if B extends A.

Comment: What do you mean work? Are you asking if the JPA provider will choke on you using the mapped superclass as opposed to the concrete entity classes? Also, depending on what `serviceLayer.getSubClassAsList();` returns, your second example might not even compile.

Comment: what about the first example?

Comment: The getSubClass method will work as it is.  For the second where you are trying to get a list it depends on how you implement the getSubClassAsList method on your service layer.  If make your declaration on your service as follows.  public List<? extends A> getSubClassAsList(){...} and your variable List<? extends A>listOfItems = serv.getSubClassAsList();  Then it will all work.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really clear but you won't be able to make a query against the super class because hibernate won't know against which table to make a request. This can be perceived as the `@Table` annotation is on your child class `B`, not on your super class `A`

In other words : You will be able to assign your result entity B to a variable A (java inheritance stuff) but you won't be able to write something like this in HQL : `from A ...` because hibernate won't know which table to query (ORM does not stand for `Object Reading Mind` (of the developer) ;) ).